# Change line transparency in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and trying to plot some regression lines but make them transparent. I read here:https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/44442-change-opacity-of-lines that it should be possible to do this by specifying the alpha as the final value in the colour, however, this does not change anything for me. Any ideas how I can make my lines transparent? I am running version R2021a.

`plot(MC_age(:,i),f(i,:),'LineWidth',0.1,"Color", [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.8])`

Thanks

Comment: Oh no how frustrating! Maybe downloading an older version and running the code through that is the way to go?

Comment: I'm using R2021a update 1, and it works fine.

Comment: I only downloaded matlab maybe a few days ago (I really am that much of a newbie!) so unfortunately it isn't that. I will try using the ```patchline()``` function once I work out how to import new packages ... haha!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I don't have 2021a, but I have tested the following code on R2020b and R2017a

```matlab
x = 1:10;
y1 = rand(size(x));
y2 = rand(size(x));
y3 = rand(size(x));

figure;hold all;
plot(x,y1,'LineWidth',10,"Color", [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1])
plot(x,y2,'LineWidth',10,"Color", [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5])
plot(x,y3,'LineWidth',10,"Color", [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2])
```

and it works as you would like, but unfortunately [it seems that others have experienced a problem doing the same thing with 2021a.](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/351255-how-can-change-transparency-and-thickness-of-a-line-in-matlab#comment_1558355)

There is [this function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36953-patchline) called `patchline()`, which essentially draws your plots as patch objects instead. Downloading it, then using the following code (in the same directory where patchline was saved)

```matlab
x = 1:10;
y1 = rand(size(x));
y2 = rand(size(x));
y3 = rand(size(x));

figure;hold all;
p1 = patchline(x,y1,'edgecolor',[0.4 0.4 0.4],'linewidth',2,'edgealpha',1);
p2 = patchline(x,y2,'edgecolor',[0.4 0.4 0.4],'linewidth',2,'edgealpha',0.5);
p3 = patchline(x,y3,'edgecolor',[0.4 0.4 0.4],'linewidth',2,'edgealpha',0.2);
```

gives me the following image

[image]

I have also tested this on 2017a and 2020b... does that work for you on 2021a?