# Plotting transparent lines in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to create a plot in MATLAB of ERP data. At present, the below code plots a waveform for 26 participant for channel 1, with mean amplitude on Y axis and time on X. I want to change the plot such that the waveforms are all light grey, but become darker where there are a lot of waves on top of one another.

```
times = Condition1.time;
channel = [1]; 

% the difference (for every participant, every channel, and every timepoint)
diff = (grandaverages.Condition1.individual) - (grandaverages.Condition2.individual);

channeldiffwaves = squeeze( mean( diff(:,channels,:), 2 ) );

% make the space to put the figure on
figure; hold on;

% list of participants to plot
plotparticipantIdx = [1:26]; 

% go through each participant
for participantIdx = plotparticipantIdx

ptpdiffwave = channeldiffwaves( participantIdx, : );

plot( times, ptpdiffwave )

end

% make a x-axis at zero
plot( times, zeros( size(times) ), 'k' )
```

[image]

How can I make all lines light gray and darkening where lines overlap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the RGB-alpha quadruplet:

```
plot(x, y, 'Color', [0 0 0 0.3]);
```

The first three entries are your standard RGB-triplet, i.e. `0 0 0` for black, then change the alpha (=transparency) between 0 (invisible) and 1 (completely visible).

As a side-note, this isn't even documented in the [Chart line appearance and behavior](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html) part of MATLAB's documentation.

<sub>I can't quite figure out when this syntax was introduced; on my R2007b it doesn't work, but from 2017 onwards this solution starts popping up on the internet, thus I presume this was introduced with the overhaul of the graphic's engine in R2016b.</sub>

Comment: Also there's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68650017/5211833) on SO suggesting to use a custom function called `patchlines`, given MATLAB doesn't (or at least didn't at the time) support transparency for line objects)

Comment: Indeed, transparency for lines was introduced with HG2, as was anti-aliasing an a whole lot more improvements.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Can I ask if there's a way to change the individual waveforms (for each participant) darker based on the degree of overlap with one another? if it's going to be a nightmare then I'll probably just stick with the effect that the transparency has.

Comment: @Jen that sounds a lot like the actual effect of transparency. If you want a different transparency for each line, you could plot each line individually and adjust its colour quadruplet accordingly. (How you determine overlap is another question altogether, but it'll probably come out as an array, which you can then set as fourth column in the colour array.)